# Show that $U^* A U$ is upper triangular, with $A$ upper triangular, and $U$ unitary and lower-Hessenberg

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, unitary-matrices, schur-decomposition

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be upper triangular.  Let $u$ be a unit-norm eigenvector of $A$ whose eigenvalue is $a_{11}$ (the top-left entry of $A$).  Let $U \in Unitary(n)$ be a [lower-Hessenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix) unitary matrix whose first column is $u$.

**Question**: Show that $U^* A U$ is an upper triangular matrix. (Or find a counterexample.)

---

Comments:

(0) Write $U = [u, U_\perp]$, where $U_\perp\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n-1}$.
Note that $U_\perp^* A U_\perp$ is upper triangular if and only if $U^* A U$ is upper triangular.  (Since $U_\perp^* A u = 0$.) It is not hard to check that the (nonsquare) matrix $U_\perp^* A$ is upper triangular.

(1) I tried to find counterexamples when $n=3, 4$, but have had no success - seems like the statement might be true.  It is not hard to come up with examples showing that the assumption that $U$ is lower Hessenberg is necessary.

(2) As $A$ is upper triangular, $e_1$ is an eigenvector of $A$.  If $a_{11}$ is a distinct eigenvalue, then $e_1$ is the unique eigenvector associated to $a_{11}$ (up to scaling).  In this case, it seems like it might be easier to prove the statement, but I'm still stuck.  Anyway, I am particularly interested in the case where the eigenvalues of $A$ are not distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out.  The key is the following lemma, which for example can be found in [Proposition 3.1 here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.02312.pdf).

**Lemma**: Let $U \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be unitary and lower-Hessenberg, and let $u_j$ denote the $j$-th column of $U$.  Then $u_j \in \mathrm{span}(u_1, e_1, \ldots, e_{j-1})$ for $j \in[2, n]$.

Now onto the proof.  Since $A$ is upper triangular and $u_1$ is an eigenvector of $A$ (by assumption), $A u_j \in \mathrm{span}(u_1, e_1, \ldots, e_{j-1})$ (applying the Lemma).  Let $i > j$.  We know $u_i^* u_1 = 0$ (by unitary-ness) and $u_i^* e_{k} = 0$ for $k < i-1$ (by Hessenberg-ness).  So $u_i^* A u_j = 0$.